# backbone and rails collection.create wait

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js

I'm trying to get the wait: true option to work on collection.create(model) and am not having any luck.

view to be rendered on add

```
window.ObjectsView = GreyboxView.extend
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    return this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    json = { obj removed }
    this.template = _.template(JST['irboards/index'](json));
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.renderObjects();
    return this;
  }
}
```

on Model Save (new)

```
window.FormView = GreyboxView.extend({
  // un-needed code omitted
  saveModel: function() {
    this.model.set { all my attributes }

    this.collection.create(this.model, {
      wait: true
    });
  }
}
```

in rails controller:

```
def create
  @model = Model.new(params[:model].merge({:account_id => current_user.account.id, :action_user_id => current_user.id}))

  if @model.save
    flash[:success] = AppSystem::Notifications.created('Model')
    respond_with @model.to_json
  else
    flash[:error] = @model.errors[:base].blank? ? AppSystem::Notifications::FORM_ERROR :   @model.errors[:base]
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Basically the {wait: true} does nothing... Either the js model is not being added to the collection, b/c it is saving to the database or the

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.render)
```

is not getting triggered or maybe rails is not returning a success... I don't really know.

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

---

Apparently I can't answer my own question yet, but I don't want to forget this b/c I know it will help others.  so:

Well... After searching for a long time and finally posting this question... I discovered the way to handle this.  I found this post/blog

http://italktoomuch.com/2012/05/setting-up-backbonejs-with-ruby-on-rails/

Basically my create :action needs to be

```
def create
  respond_with = Model.create(params0
end
```

and the js is:

```
this.collection.create(attributes, {
  wait: false,
  success: function() {
    return _this.collection.trigger('reset');
  },
  error: function() {
    return alert('wrong!');
  }
})
```

So am I left to believe the wait does nothing? or am I just using it wrong?  I don't know but this is working and I am happy.  Need to do a little more refactoring but this is a good place to start

Hope this helps others as well

Answer (score 1):

`{wait:true}` certainly does something! :-)

I don't know anything about rails but here is what I think might be the issue. Basically when you pass the option `wait:true` backbone will wait for a server response before creating or destroying your model, thereby adding or removing it from the collection only after it's verified that the resource has been saved or deleted.

Thus, the important component to using `wait:true` is to make sure your server response includes a proper HTTP status. Return a status of 200 if it's OKAY and something like 400, or 500 if it is not. Take a pick. I'm not quite sure if your code does this or not although it's something to check.

To note further, seems you added a success and error callback to your code. Basically this is also how Backbone knows whether or not to call the success or error. 200 and it executes the success. Anything other and it runs the error.

By default (currently) Backbone is optimistic, meaning if you pass nothing (or `wait:false`) Backbone assumes everything is going to work out all right. So it will trigger your add or destroy events before getting a response from your server.